# How to choose a time series database?

Tags: database, time-series

I found there are great number of time series databases emerged these years. There is even [A long list of emerged TS-databases](http://www.erol.si/2015/01/the-complete-list-of-all-timeseries-databases-for-your-iot-project/), updated in Jan 2015.

I wonder what different capabilities they have, or what strengths and weaknesses do they have? - otherwise we just need one TS database, don't we?

Comment: You might want to add information about your particular use case/dataset, otherwise the question is too broad, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am doing a project which related to monitoring hundreds of machines' metrics. The data volume may be 20 MB/s or higher. As I have limited experience on this, I don't quite know how to compare different TS databases. So I am asking for a broad view of those TS databases, and what their uniquenesses are.

Comment: Assuming command length (hostname+metric+timestamp+value+2 tags) is 100 symbols, 20 Mb/s is 20*2^20/100=2 mln inserts per second. Congrats, you're playing in big league now. This type of ingestion rate disqualifies most time series databases from the above list. In fact, it'd be hard to find a review that matches your particular use case. It's a good case for DIY tests.